# How do I change the location of screenshot in OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, terminal, screen-capture, preferences

The old method that works for Leopard/Snow Leopard doesn't work any more on Lion:

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture location /Users/kamus/Pictures/snap
```

Has something changed or does anyone have some good workarounds?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps it's because your path isn't really a path to a folder:
Notice to terminating `/`:

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture location /Users/kamus/Pictures/snap/
```

Comment: Note to any other boneheads like me out there: this doesn't take effect until you log out and back in.

Comment: @AbbyT.Miller No need to log out, just enter this in terminal: `killall SystemUIServer`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [TinkerTool](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html) to accomplish the same thing. I've found that TinkerTool is much easier than having to remember a whole bunch of `defaults write com.apple...` commands. It has all of the most useful ones in one place for you to easily change. You can find the screenshot destination one under the General tab:

[image]

(as noted by [this comment,](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33154/how-do-i-change-the-location-of-screenshot-in-os-x-lion#comment65207_33155) you *don't* have to log out and back in again, just use the Terminal command `killall SystemUIServer`)