# Change Image Format of a Screenshot

Tags: macos

Lets say I want to save my screenshots as a .jpg instead of .png. How would I do this? Is there a bash command I can enter or a setting I can toggle?

Comment: Be aware that lossy formats like JPEG will introduce compression artifacts that make your screenshots look worse.

Comment: if (like i was), you are also wanting to change the string format of how the file is named, see here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4139/how-do-i-change-the-location-of-screen-captures-on-10-5#111320

Answer (score 14):

You can use the following Terminal command to change the default screenshot format (I'm reading that GIF and PDF and some other formats are also supported):

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture type jpg
```

(You can also set the `location` key to a path to a directory in which you'd like the screenshots to be saved, as opposed to your Desktop.)

Also, the [screencapture](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/screencapture.1.html) command can be used to save a screenshot to a specific filename, and configure more options (such as window shadows, timed capture, etc.).

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following Terminal command to change the default location that they are stored in, and then use a folder action to perform conversion and other actions if required.

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture location ~/Pictures/
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the free application [TinkerTool](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html) to do that as well. It's under the General pane: 
[image: General pane of Tinkertool]
<del>(Note that you'll have to log out and log back in for the changes to take effect.)</del>

(as noted by [this comment,](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33154/how-do-i-change-the-location-of-screenshot-in-os-x-lion#comment65207_33155) you *don't* have to log out and back in again, just use the Terminal command `killall SystemUIServer`)